# Find the Regular conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given $\mu = 2\lambda_{|D}$ with $D:=\{(x,y): 0\leq x\leq y\leq 1\}$ and
$(\Omega , \mathfrak{F}, \mathbb{P})=(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathfrak{B}^2, \mu)$.

If $Y(x,y):=x$ find the Regular conditional probability for $\sigma (Y)$.

---

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability

The problem looks like playing Dart and trying to calculate the probability for the value of the x-Axis for the hits.

$\lambda$ stands for Lebesgue-measure

Any help on this?